# XML not parsing in IE8

Tags: jquery, xml, internet-explorer-8

EDIT: thanks to charlietfl I realized that IE < 9 converts all XML tags to uppercase. However, enven with this knowledge I have not been able to find a solution to get the XML to display properly in IE8.

I have this working in all good browsers, IE10 and 9 but in IE8 there is no xml data being parsed/displayed.

```
$("#Form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $('#prcs3').show();
        var dataString = $(form).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: $(form).attr('method'),
            url: form.action,
            data: dataString,
            clearForm: true,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#resultGenerate > li').remove();
                var answer = $(data).find("td:eq(3)").text();
                var message = $(data).find("td:eq(5)").html();
                var $xml = $( message );
                if (answer==="True") {
                    $('#prcs3').hide();
                    $xml.find('license').each(function(){
                        var CustomerID = $(this).find('CustomerID').text();
                        var License  = $(this).find('License').text();
                        var Log  = $(this).find('Log').text();
                        var ExpirationDate  = $(this).find('ExpirationDate').text();
                        $("#resultGenerate").show().removeClass('error').append($('<li><span class="ID">' + CustomerID + '</span><span class="L">' + License + '</span><span class="Log">' + Log + '</span><span class="Exp">' + ExpirationDate + '</span></li>'));
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#prcs3').hide();
                    $('#resultGenerate').show().html('<a class="close">X</a><ul><li>' + message + '</li></ul>');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

What could be causing IE8 to not display my returned/parsed xml? I appreciate any advice, as always thank you.

Comment: is it xml or html being returned? You can't use `html()` method on xml. Provide a sample

Comment: it is xml inside of a table, this was the only way I could get it to go through the table, find the right td and parse it from there.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing sample of the returned response I am gathering that the xml is text inside an html table being returned.

You will likely need to use `$.parseXML()`

Try:

```
var $xml = $( $.parseXML( message) );
```

API reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

**EDIT:** In addition IE versions below 9 will translate the tags to all uppercase. You can get around this by checking for `length`

```
if( $xml.find('LICENCES').length ){
    /* use all uppercase tagnames*/
}else{
    /* use all lowercase tagnames*/
}
```

Comment: using the above, it breaks the output in browsers that it was working in and still doesn't output anything in IE8

Comment: need to see sample of response returned...can you post to jsfiddle.net. Also make sure html is 100% valid, IE hates invalid markup in ajax. Is possibe that the xml tags mixed in html are a problem

Comment: seems like a very strange way to return xml... have you considered JSON?

Comment: Here is sample of returned xml <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?-->
<licenses><license>
<XXXcustomerid>afdsfadfadsf</XXXcustomerid>
<XXlicense>225D-D729-3B10-5733-5671-50C2-8A44-65EB</XXlicense>
<log>Created by lt@XXXX.com on December 7, 2012, 5:31 pm Cancelled by lt@XXXX.com on December 7, 2012, 5:31 pm</log>
<expirationdate>2013-01-01</expirationdate>
</license></licenses>

Comment: when I use the var $xml = $($.parseXML(message); I see them with a console.log(message) - but nothing is appending to my content area

Comment: OK   I found the problem and have run into this trying to parse html strings before in IE < 9. IE makes all the tags uppercase. You will need to check for both uppar and lowercase. Try this in IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/M2wg3/4/

Comment: in the end..really not clear why you need to send xml inside html. Would be far better to use one or the other or use json to send both

Comment: It would make a lot more sense to send it as json. Unfortunately this is out of my hands. However, your catch on IE < 9 switching to all uppercase is awesome. I just alerted the value for 'message' and comparing chrome to IE8 shows all tags have indeed been changed to uppercase.

Comment: I realized it by logging the string to console in the demo also...and then remembered html regex parsing issues I had before with same problem

Comment: So you're basically saying to just change all my .find(XMLTAGNAME) to uppercase? the js fiddle didn't do anything, not sure if it was suposed to?

Comment: fiddle is appending `afdsfadfadsf` to body from one tag in `LICENCE` for me in IE 8. If you don't have console installed in IE, remove the `console.log` in fiddle and hit `run` again. See my suggestion in answer edit also
`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20853/discussion-between-dirty-bird-design-and-charlietfl)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with `var $xml = $( message );`, as I ran it through JSlint and this was the only non-jQuery related error. Does `var $xml = $(message);` fix it?

EDIT: Try removing the `$` before `$(form).serialize();`, as the jQuery website (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) has an example showing that problems can occur with that.

Comment: Hi Wilson, no that doesn't seem to fix it. In IE8's limited developer tools, its showing "Expected identifier line XXX(the if (answer==="True") line and an Exception thrown and not caught in jquery.min

Comment: use jQuery development version to debug, will be able to see what method is causing problems. Is very hard to do with minified version

Comment: not familiar with that - where do you find hosted files for this? can't find them on google jquery cdn

Comment: thats because its not loading jquery.validate

Comment: $xml = $( message ); nor $xml = $(message); do the trick. I added an alert(message); right after that line, it alerts the xml but it just won't parse/append it to the content block.

Answer (score 0):

I was using IE10 and was having the same problem. The link [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-doesn-t-return-xml-with-internet-explorer-10) described me the issue. So, in short, firstly I checked the browser if it was IE (as xml was being parsed successfully by other browsers) and then converted my response string. Hope the following code snippet helps:

```
function getXMLData(str)
{
    var MSIE = jQuery.support.leadingWhitespace;//detects if browser is IE 
     if(MSIE)if browser is IE 
     {
      if ( ! $.isXMLDoc(str))//if str is not in XML, make it xml
       str = $.parseXML(str)
      var xmlDoc=str;
     }
     else//for other browsers, take the response string as it is
     {
      var html = XMLToString(str);//gives back string from xml string
      var xml = html;
      var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
     }

     var $xml =$( xmlDoc ),
     $title = $xml.find( "string" );//find the 'string' element from xml
     //do the rest of the processing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I make a wild guess here:

```
    success: function(data) {
        $('#resultGenerate > li').remove();
        var answer = $(data).find("td:eq(3)").text();
        var message = $(data).find("td:eq(5)").html();
        var $xml = $( message );
```

I think you have to `parseXML` data first. So,

```
    success: function(data) {
        $('#resultGenerate > li').remove();
        var $data = $( $.parseXML(data) );
        var answer = $data.find("td:eq(3)").text();
        var message = $data.find("td:eq(5)").html();
        var $xml = $( message );
```